# Android Compose Like Google Week Calendar

Tags: android, android-studio, calendar, android-jetpack-compose, composable

I wanted to replicate the Google week calendar view in compose but got stuck on the scrolling. I use the `detectTransformGestures()` to zoom and translate the content but once I let go of the fingers the translation stops. How would you go about adding scrolling behavior which continues scrolling once you let go (just like a normal Recyclerview or `.scrolling()` in compose).

I have found https://github.com/alamkanak/Android-Week-View but seems overly complicated and is used in xml. I want something cleaner and easier to use.

Here is my current code. The content is not yet limited to top and bottom and you can scale how much or little you want.

```kotlin
@Composable
fun WeekCalendar() {

    var scaleY by remember {
        mutableStateOf(1f)
    }
    var offset by remember {
        mutableStateOf(0f)
    }

    var centroi by remember {
        mutableStateOf(0f)
    }



    Canvas(modifier = Modifier

        .pointerInput(Unit) {
            this.detectTransformGestures() { centroid, pan, zoom, rotation ->

                scaleY *= zoom
                offset += pan.y * zoom
                // center zooming around point location
                offset += (zoom - 1) * (offset - centroid.y)
                centroi = centroid.y
            }
        }
        .fillMaxWidth()
        .height(1200.dp)
    ) {
        val bottom = size.height * scaleY + offset
        val top = offset

        drawLine(
            color = Color.Red,
            start = Offset(0f, top),
            end = Offset(size.width, top),
        )

        drawLine(
            color = Color.Red,
            start = Offset(size.width, top),
            end = Offset(size.width, bottom),
        )

        drawLine(
            color = Color.Red,
            start = Offset(size.width, bottom),
            end = Offset(0f, bottom),
        )

        drawLine(
            color = Color.Red,
            start = Offset(0f, bottom),
            end = Offset(0f, top),
        )

        drawLine(
            color = Color.Red,
            start = Offset(0f, top),
            end = Offset(size.width, bottom),
        )

        drawPoints(listOf(Offset(size.width / 2, centroi)), PointMode.Points, color = Color.Blue, strokeWidth = 5f)
    }
}
```

Comment: Did you finish the implementation, since I am trying to do a week calendar using compose and inflated this library. But found some difficulties in using it till now.

Comment: @EliodeBeirut I figured out that it's not possible to do in Compose yet. So I created and Android Custom View instead. The View works but I did not finish the ability to render "block" such as scheduled appointments. Can be found here: https://github.com/OscarCreator/Android-Week-View